# Exact dimensions in tcolorbox-4

Tags: tcolorbox, polyglossia, arabic

I have a problem, related with this question: [Exact dimensions in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395867/exact-dimensions-in-tcolorbox).

I produce several kinds of environment, 'definition', 'proposition' etc, and I want to uniformize my work for several cases of environments, i.e. make a general box, which apply on all kinds of environments (here, the two environments, definition and proposition for my example).

I made an environment, 'mybox', where I attempt for this work. I can code the colour of the rules as variable for this envirobment, with the `Col#2` command, #2 can be definition or proposition, but the node `\#2node` (which must be `\propositionnode` and `\definitionnode`, for these example) is not recognized, as viewed in the compilation. How can I repair this?

The project  of code, based on the original .tex file cited, is here:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\colorlet{Colproposition}{blue}
\colorlet{Coldefinition}{green}

\newcounter{definition}[chapter]
\newcounter{proposition}[chapter]


\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{definition}}
\newcommand{\definitionlabel}{\textbf{Def \thedefinition}}
\newcommand{\definitionnode}{%
\node[fill=Coldefinition!5!white, draw=Coldefinition!75!black, line width=.5pt, below right, minimum height=2em, 
    text width=.8cm, align=center] at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {\definitionlabel}}


\renewcommand{\theproposition}{\arabic{proposition}}
\newcommand{\propositionlabel}{\textbf{Prop \theproposition}}
\newcommand{\propositionnode}{%
\node[fill=Colproposition!5!white, draw=Colproposition!75!black, line width=.5pt, below right, minimum height=2em, 
    text width=.8cm, align=center] at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {\propositionlabel}}


\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{definition}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,colback=white,colframe=white,arc=0mm,rightrule=0mm,leftrule=0mm,toprule=0mm,
bottomrule=0mm,top=2mm,bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,extrude right by=-15mm,
before upper={\parshape 4
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \hsize},
underlay unbroken and first={%
    \definitionnode;
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=15mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(-\textwidth/4,0);
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(0,-10mm);
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(\textwidth/4,0);
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(0,-10mm);
    },
underlay unbroken and last={%
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0)--(0,0);
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(0,10mm);
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)--+(0,10mm);
    \draw [Coldefinition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0)--(\textwidth,0);
    }
]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}}

\newenvironment{proposition}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{proposition}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,colback=white,colframe=white,arc=0mm,rightrule=0mm,leftrule=0mm,toprule=0mm,
bottomrule=0mm,top=2mm,bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,
before upper={\parshape 4
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \hsize},
extrude right by=-15mm,
underlay unbroken and first={%
    \propositionnode;
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=15mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(-\textwidth/4,0);
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(0,-10mm);
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(\textwidth/4,0);
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(0,-10mm);
    },
underlay unbroken and last={%
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0)--(0,0);
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(0,10mm);
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)--+(0,10mm);
    \draw [Colproposition!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0)--(\textwidth,0);
    }
]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}}

\newenvironment{mybox}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{#2}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,colback=white,colframe=white,arc=0mm,rightrule=0mm,leftrule=0mm,toprule=0mm,
bottomrule=0mm,top=2mm,bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,extrude right by=-15mm,
before upper={\parshape 4
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
    0pt \hsize},
underlay unbroken and first={%
    \#2node;
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=15mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(-\textwidth/4,0);
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(0,-10mm);
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(\textwidth/4,0);
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(0,-10mm);
    },
underlay unbroken and last={%
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0)--(0,0);
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(0,10mm);
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)--+(0,10mm);
    \draw [Col#2!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0)--(\textwidth,0);
    }
]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{definition}
A  definition produced by the 'definition' environment
\vspace{1cm}
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}
A  proposition produced by the 'proposition' environment
\vspace{1cm}
\end{proposition}


\begin{mybox}{proposition}
A  proposition produced by the 'mybox' environment
\vspace{1cm}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{definition}
A  definition produced by the 'mybox' environment
\vspace{1cm}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

which gives this after compilation, where one can see that the node of title doesn't appear in the box :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to define several `styles` which will be used inside `tcolorbox` definitions.

In this `mystyle` defines the general box with two arguments, the first is the color and the second the label which is used in the upper right box.

The upper right box is defined with a `\newcommand` with two arguments, the label and the color.

Another style is defined for the title. This definition doesn't consider the solution applied in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395963/1952.

Again, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396010/1952 originally proposed environments have been replaced by `\newtcolorboxes`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Arial}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below right, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=.8cm, align=center,
   font=\bfseries] at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style 2 args={
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable, 
        colback=white, colframe=white, 
        sharp corners, 
        boxrule = 0mm, 
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,
        varwidth boxed title,
        attach boxed title to top right={%
            xshift=.5mm,yshift=- \tcboxedtitleheight+.5mm},
        boxed title style={%
            enhanced,
            sharp corners, 
            colframe=#1!75!black, 
            right=1mm,
            boxrule=.5mm},
        colbacktitle=#1!5!white, 
        coltitle=black,
        extrude right by=-15mm,
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(0,-15mm);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=15mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north east)--+(-\textwidth/4,0);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(\textwidth/4,0);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.north west)--+(0,-15mm);
        },
        underlay unbroken and last={%
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0)--(0,0);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(0,15mm);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)--+(0,15mm);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0)--(\textwidth,0);
        },
    },
    mytitle/.style={
        code={%
            \ifstrempty{#1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize}}}
            {\tcbset{
                title={#1},
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize}}}
        },
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop},
    mytitle={#2},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def},
    mytitle={#2},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
A non-titled definition
\vspace{2.2cm}
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
A titled proposition
\vspace{2cm}
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[height=2cm]{Another long title}
A titled definition
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

I've changed `varwidth boxed node` to `tikznode boxed node`. This way it's possible to fix a `minimum width` to solve the short titles problem.

The problem with the lower right line it's solved drawing the `default` corner and in case of titled boxes, draw again the lower line till the title end.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Arial}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below right, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=.8cm, align=center,
   font=\bfseries] at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style 2 args={
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable, 
        colback=white, colframe=white, 
        sharp corners, 
        boxrule = 0mm, 
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,
%       varwidth boxed title,
        tikznode boxed title={minimum width=\textwidth/4-15mm-4.5mm},
        attach boxed title to top right={%
            xshift=.5mm,yshift=- \tcboxedtitleheight+.5mm},
        boxed title style={%
            enhanced,
            sharp corners, 
            colframe=#1!75!black, 
            left=1mm, right=1mm,
            boxrule=.5mm},
        colbacktitle=#1!5!white, 
        coltitle=black,
        extrude right by=-15mm,
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([shift={(15mm-.5\pgflinewidth,-15mm+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east)|-([shift={(-\textwidth/4+15mm,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-15mm+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west)|-([shift={(\textwidth/4,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west);        },
        underlay unbroken and last={%
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0)--(0,0);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(0,15mm);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)--+(0,15mm);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0)--(\textwidth,0);
        },
    },
    mytitle/.style 2 args={
        code={%
            \ifstrempty{#1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize}}}
            {\tcbset{
                title={#1},
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize},
                underlay unbroken and last={
                    \draw [#2!75!black,line width=.5mm](frame.south east)--++(180:\tcboxedtitlewidth-\pgflinewidth);
                }}}
        },
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop},
    mytitle={#2}{blue},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def},
    mytitle={#2}{green},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
A non-titled definition
\vspace{2.2cm}
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
A titled proposition
\vspace{2cm}
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[height=2cm]{A}
A titled definition
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the different environments, I have different ways to number it. So what must we do if we want to have my propositions numbered like this way for example `\renewcommand{\theproposition}{\arabic{chapter}\Alph{proposition}}` ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna   Look at "counters" section in tcolorbox documentation. You can use something like `auto counter, after=chapter`.

Comment: ok thanks I'll see it. I absolutely want a litteral counter a,b,c so I hope that it's possible with auto counter !

Comment: How can I apply your solution to the case of my other question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395867/exact-dimensions-in-tcolorbox/395963#395963 where you proposed a solution where the south rule is as longer as the titled rule?

Comment: Other thing. What about the "small titles", like `\begin{proposition}{}{A title}` which ends before the end of the north east rule, where the output is not very beautiful ? How can we do a title box with length is at least the length of the rule ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna I've updated the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: J just saw your update, cos' an error on my system or I don't know what ! Thank you for your ingenious solution, that solves all my remaining problems about this. I'll have just a little improvment on my boxes. I'll open a last question on this. Many thanks for all

Comment: Would you see this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397033/use-of-tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode-as-a-length-in-tcolorbox related to the use of something like 
`\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode` in my boxes. Many thanks